# How to set sequence data with existing random data?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table entity named it as uniqueId where the entry generate randomly.Such as

```
$customer->uniqueId = $request->Input(['uniqueId']) ?: mt_rand(1000, 9999);
```

means if there is existing uniqueId it will store the existing one otherwise it will be set to the random number. Now instead of setting the random number i want to set it as sequentially . means  from 1, 2, 3 like that.. as i can't delete the existing uniqueId which has already created how do I create new entry sequentially with the existing one?

Comment: is uniqueId is primary key?

Comment: no it's just a entry but it's unique ..means other user shouldn't have same id

Comment: where/how do you store $customer(s)?

Comment: I used laravel as a tool, i created $customer object to store the uniqueId in customers table..I might not get your Question

Answer (score 0):

If you simply set column to auto increment you will achieve this automatically you dont even need to call it.

In laravel you can achieve this in your migrations by

`$table->increments('uniqueId');`

**OR**

You can achieve this by

lets assume you have a customer Model

```
 // find the last entry in you table

$oldCustomer = Customer::orderBy('uniqueId','DESC')->first();

$customer->uniqueId = ++($olderCustomer->uniqueId);
```

I hope this helps

**EDIT **

```
  $customers = Customer::all();

  $index = 1;
  @foreach($customers as $customer)
  {
      $customer->uniqueID = $index++;
      $customer->update(); 
  }
```

Comment: i may failed to make you understandable what my Question is..suppose the uniqueId has value like 4435 then 6784 and then 2345 ..now I want to set sequence number like 1 2 3 4 instead of this random number ..but my existing database shouldn't be effected means i don't want to uniqueId entry as after 2345 -> 2346 i want after 2345 as 1 then next entry should be 2 3 like that